# Merging dataframe cells based on content

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I have an ugly dataframe I inherited, like so:

```
data.bad <- data.frame(
'NameId' = c('350-8D6A','BC2-85E2','426-C0FA','615-8E09','651-8D6F','DE8-3D0F','2B6-D039','5E9-EE00','38F-75E4','B02-FBBC','B7A-821E','95A-B349','A8C-4A7B','3F6-90A1'),
'Tribe' = c('Heliantheae','Heliantheae','Cichorieae','Cichorieae','Cichorieae','Senecioneae','Vernonieae','Tageteae','Vernonieae','Vernonieae','Millerieae','Inuleae','Astereae','Cardueae'),
'NameFull' = c('Wedelia mexicana (Sch.Bip.) McVaugh','Wedelia modesta Baker','Youngia multiflora (Thunb.) DC.','Youngia napifera DC. ex Wight','Scorzonera mucida Rech.f. Aellen & Esfand.','Senecio hualtaranensis Petenatti Ariza & Del Vitto','Baccharoides tolypophora (Mattf.) Isawumi El-Ghazaly & B.Nord.','Bajacalia crassifolia (S.Watson) Loockerman B.L.Turner & R.K.Jansen','Vernonia westermanii Ekman & Dusen','Vernonia westiniana Less.','Oteiza scandens Panero Villaseeor & Medina','Pulicaria hesperia Maire Weiller & Wilczek','Aster chusanensis Y.S.Lim','Cheirolophus mansanetianus Stubing'),
'Status' = c('Accepted','Accepted','Synonym','Synonym','Accepted','Accepted','Synonym','Synonym','Unknown','Unknown','Unknown','Unknown','Hyun','J.B.Peris'),
'AcceptedName' = c('Wedelia mexicana (Sch.Bip.) McVaugh','Wedelia modesta Baker','Youngia japonica (L.) DC.','Youngia japonica (L.) DC.','','','','','NULL','NULL','','','Y.D.Kim & H.C.Shin','Olivares & J.Marten')
)
```

- Column 1: Alpha numeric identifier - Fine
- Column 2: Higher level classification, single name - Fine
- Column 3: varying length string representing a species name and author(s) - sometimes missing some text that has been split into col(s) 4 (and sometimes 5) - it looks like left over commas at some point split the text but are no longer in the data.
- Column 4: validity of name as a single word - *should* be either "Accepted", "Synonym", or "NULL" but in some cases is empty and in worst cases has text that should be in col 3.
- Column 5: Accepted name - Should contain valid binomial and author (similar to column 3). The contents of column 5 should be: the same as column 3 if column 4 = "Accepted"; different if "Synonym"; and "NULL" if "Unknown") but sometimes has fragments of text from column 3, and is sometimes empty (and cannot be inferred from other columns here).

Rows 1-4,9,10 are examples of correct formatting.
Rows 13,14 are messed up and need to merge the contents of cols 4 and 5 into col 3 (with commas in between), and the newly empty cols 4 and 5 populated with "FLAG" to indicate to me that they need attention.
Rows 5-8,11,12, are missing data in col 5 which can be extrapolated from col 4 ("Accepted" = contents of col 3; "Synonym" = "FLAG" (to indicate to me missing data); "Unknown" = "NULL").

The ideal outcome would be:

```
data.best <- data.frame(
  'NameId' = c('350-8D6A','BC2-85E2','426-C0FA','615-8E09','651-8D6F','DE8-3D0F','2B6-D039','5E9-EE00','38F-75E4','B02-FBBC','B7A-821E','95A-B349','A8C-4A7B','3F6-90A1'),
  'Tribe' = c('Heliantheae','Heliantheae','Cichorieae','Cichorieae','Cichorieae','Senecioneae','Vernonieae','Tageteae','Vernonieae','Vernonieae','Millerieae','Inuleae','Astereae','Cardueae'),
  'NameFull' = c('Wedelia mexicana (Sch.Bip.) McVaugh','Wedelia modesta Baker','Youngia multiflora (Thunb.) DC.','Youngia napifera DC. ex Wight','Scorzonera mucida Rech.f. Aellen & Esfand.','Senecio hualtaranensis Petenatti Ariza & Del Vitto','Baccharoides tolypophora (Mattf.) Isawumi El-Ghazaly & B.Nord.','Bajacalia crassifolia (S.Watson) Loockerman B.L.Turner & R.K.Jansen','Vernonia westermanii Ekman & Dusen','Vernonia westiniana Less.','Oteiza scandens Panero Villaseeor & Medina','Pulicaria hesperia Maire Weiller & Wilczek','Aster chusanensis Y.S.Lim, Hyun, Y.D.Kim & H.C.Shin','Cheirolophus mansanetianus Stubing, J.B.Peris, Olivares & J.Marten'),
  'Status' = c('Accepted','Accepted','Synonym','Synonym','Accepted','Accepted','Synonym','Synonym','Unknown','Unknown','Unknown','Unknown','FLAG','FLAG'),
  'AcceptedName' = c('Wedelia mexicana (Sch.Bip.) McVaugh','Wedelia modesta Baker','Youngia japonica (L.) DC.','Youngia japonica (L.) DC.','Scorzonera mucida Rech.f. Aellen & Esfand.','Senecio hualtaranensis Petenatti Ariza & Del Vitto','FLAG','FLAG','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','FLAG','FLAG')
)
```

This has too many moving parts for me. All the examples I can find are merging two separate dataframes, but not conditional upon elements in an existing dataframe.

NB: a partial solution just merging the errant text in cols 4 and 5 back into col 3would be a very nice start (below), but obviously would love a neat full solution!

```
data.good <- data.frame(
  'NameId' = c('350-8D6A','BC2-85E2','426-C0FA','615-8E09','651-8D6F','DE8-3D0F','2B6-D039','5E9-EE00','38F-75E4','B02-FBBC','B7A-821E','95A-B349','A8C-4A7B','3F6-90A1'),
  'Tribe' = c('Heliantheae','Heliantheae','Cichorieae','Cichorieae','Cichorieae','Senecioneae','Vernonieae','Tageteae','Vernonieae','Vernonieae','Millerieae','Inuleae','Astereae','Cardueae'),
  'NameFull' = c('Wedelia mexicana (Sch.Bip.) McVaugh','Wedelia modesta Baker','Youngia multiflora (Thunb.) DC.','Youngia napifera DC. ex Wight','Scorzonera mucida Rech.f. Aellen & Esfand.','Senecio hualtaranensis Petenatti Ariza & Del Vitto','Baccharoides tolypophora (Mattf.) Isawumi El-Ghazaly & B.Nord.','Bajacalia crassifolia (S.Watson) Loockerman B.L.Turner & R.K.Jansen','Vernonia westermanii Ekman & Dusen','Vernonia westiniana Less.','Oteiza scandens Panero Villaseeor & Medina','Pulicaria hesperia Maire Weiller & Wilczek','Aster chusanensis Y.S.Lim, Hyun, Y.D.Kim & H.C.Shin','Cheirolophus mansanetianus Stubing, J.B.Peris, Olivares & J.Marten'),
  'Status' = c('Accepted','Accepted','Synonym','Synonym','Accepted','Accepted','Synonym','Synonym','Unknown','Unknown','Unknown','Unknown','',''),
  'AcceptedName' = c('Wedelia mexicana (Sch.Bip.) McVaugh','Wedelia modesta Baker','Youngia japonica (L.) DC.','Youngia japonica (L.) DC.','','','','','NULL','NULL','','','','')
)
```

Hope that makes some sort of sense, happy to clarify.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need any merge here, just a basic manipulation of the data.frame with conditional statements. Also, at rows 3 and 4 of your data.best, you didn't leave the AcceptedName as "FLAG", despite their "Synonym" status. Is that right?

Comment: Hi @CainãMaxCouto-Silva,
Hmmm, ok. I guess I'll look that route, tho help appreciated!

That is right. Rows 3 and 4 area already correctly populated in the original corrupt dataframe - the name is already recorded as different (a synonym) from the "NameFull" column. It's where the "Status" column is "synonym" but the "Accepted Name" field is empty that I need a flag as there is no way of inferring the contents of these cells with the given data :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, no merging required in this problem. Also, I would recommend using `data.table` package to solve your problem, once it's simpler to perform modifications at specific rows based on conditions.

A solution using `data.table` would be:

```
# Load data.table
library(data.table)

# Set data.bad as data.table
setDT(data.bad)

# Define Valid Status
valid_status <- c("Accepted", "Synonym", "Unknown")

# Join invalid status to NameFull column
data.bad[!Status %in% valid_status, NameFull := paste(NameFull, Status, sep = ", ")]
# then flag invalid status
data.bad[!Status %in% valid_status, Status := "FLAG"]

# Join AcceptedName to NameFull if Status == FLAG (and Accepted Name is not NULL)
data.bad[Status == "FLAG" & AcceptedName != "NULL", NameFull := paste(NameFull, AcceptedName, sep = ", ")]

# Fix column 5
data.bad[Status == "Accepted", AcceptedName := NameFull]
data.bad[Status == "Synonym" & AcceptedName == "", AcceptedName := "FLAG"]
data.bad[Status == "Unknown", AcceptedName := "NULL"]
data.bad[Status == "FLAG" & !AcceptedName %in% c("FLAG", "NULL"), AcceptedName := "FLAG"]

# Now, data.bad is data.good
data.good <- copy(data.bad)
```

If you wanna set the data back to `data.frame` class, just type `setDF(data.good)`.

Using R base:

```
# Define Valid Status
valid_status <- c("Accepted", "Synonym", "Unknown")

# Join invalid status to NameFull column
idx <- !data.bad$Status %in% valid_status # set invalid status indexes
data.bad$NameFull[idx] = paste(data.bad$NameFull[idx], data.bad$Status[idx], sep = ", ")
# then flag invalid status
data.bad$Status[idx] <- "FLAG"

# Join AcceptedName to NameFull if Status == FLAG (and Accepted Name is not NULL)
idx <- data.bad$Status == "FLAG" & data.bad$AcceptedName != "NULL"  # get indexes with status == "FLAG"
data.bad$NameFull[idx] <- paste(data.bad$NameFull[idx], data.bad$AcceptedName[idx], sep = ", ")

# Fix column 5
data.bad$AcceptedName[data.bad$Status == "Accepted"] <- data.bad$NameFull[data.bad$Status == "Accepted"]
data.bad$AcceptedName[data.bad$Status == "Synonym" & data.bad$AcceptedName == ""] <- "FLAG"
data.bad$AcceptedName[data.bad$Status == "Unknown"] <- "NULL"
data.bad$AcceptedName[data.bad$Status == "FLAG" & !data.bad$AcceptedName %in% c("FLAG", "NULL")] <- "FLAG"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm and gives me a great template for future corrupt dataframe issues that are guaranteed in my future.
Thank you!